# HTML::Entities formatting issue?

Tags: perl, unicode

I'm trying to decode the HTML character along with `\u` character in perl. So I tried, the below one

```
use Encode;
use HTML::Entities;

my $cont= do{local $/; <DATA> };
$cont=Remove_Spaces($cont);
print "$cont\n";
sub Remove_Spaces
{
    my $clean=shift;
    $clean =~s/\\u00(\w{2})/encode("utf-8",chr(hex($1)))/egs;
    #$clean=~s/(\&\#?\w+\;)/decode_entities($1)/egs;
    $clean=~s/^\s+|\s+$//igs;
    $clean=~s/\s+/ /igs;
    return $clean;
}

__DATA__
sympa et comp\u00e9ten c\u00e2ble 19&euro; e
```

I'm expecting output is

```
sympa et compéten câble 19€ some data
```

---

But when I run the script with HTML::Entities it gives the result as follow,

```
sympa et compÃ©ten cÃ¢ble 19€ e
```

Above output unicode characters all are wrongly formated.

---

When I'm comment the HTML::Entities it gives the following results,

```
sympa et compéten câble 19&euro; e
```

Above output entities characters all not formated.

I don't know what is the problem here.

---

I also tried single character substitution (As same RegEx substitution)

```
sub Remove_Spaces
{
    my $clean=shift;
    $clean=~s/\s*<[^>]*?>\s*/ /igs;
    while($clean=~m/(\&\#?\w+\;)/igs)
    {
        my $find    = $1;
        my $replace = decode_entities($find);
        my $pos = index($clean, $find);
        while($pos > -1) 
        {
            substr($clean, $pos, length($find), $replace);
            $pos = index($clean, $find, $pos + length($replace));
        }
    }

    while($clean=~m/(\\u00(\w{2}))/igs)
    {
        my $find    = $1;

        my $replace = encode("utf8",chr(hex($2)));
        #print ord($replace),"\t$replace***\n";     

        my $pos = index($clean, $find);
        while($pos > -1) 
        {
            substr($clean, $pos, length($find), $replace);

            $pos = index($clean, $find, $pos + length($replace));
        }
    }

    $clean=~s/^\s+|\s+$//igs;
    $clean=~s/\s+/ /igs;
    return $clean;
}
```

In the above code I'm replacing only one character using `substr`. Then why is will affect the `\u` characters?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The `chr` built-in function already returns Unicode characters in Perl's internal encoding, so your use of `encode` is not correct here. If anything, you would *decode* your input data, but that wouldn't be correct here, either.

I removed the call to `encode` and also made a few other minor changes, such as calling `decode_entities` on the entire string instead of selectively via an executable substitution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Entities;

sub Remove_Spaces {
    my $clean = shift;
    $clean =~ s/\\u00(\w{2})/chr(hex($1))/eg;  # match should probably be: ([0-9a-f]{2})
    $clean =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    $clean =~ s/\s+/ /g;
    return decode_entities($clean);
}

my $cont = do { local $/; <DATA> };
$cont = Remove_Spaces($cont);
binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(utf8)');  # avoid 'wide character in print' warnings
print "$cont\n";

__DATA__
sympa et comp\u00e9ten c\u00e2ble 19&euro; e
```

Output:

```
sympa et compéten câble 19€ e
```

Comment: Yep it will give the result what I'm looking for. I already tried it but the problem is `binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(utf8)');` it is decode the all kind of characters. For example, let consider the following Bulgarian character `Сокоизтисквачка ` it will decode by the `binmode`

Comment: I solved this problem by `$clean=~s/(\&\#?\w+\;)/encode("utf-8",decode_entities($1))/egs` this code. But I cannot understand what is the reason behind to encode the all character when using HTML::Entities.

Comment: `$clean=~s/(\&\#?\w+\;)/decode_entities($1)/e‌​gs` it means It will replace the particular character only. Why then `\u` character getting replaced.?